# Memcached and Redis Setup and Configuration

Tags: session, caching, composer-php, laravel-5

yesterday i asked a question about building a cart with laravel and angular, my question was on how to make interactions with my cart easier because i had my cart stored in my database as a table and felt the numerous database interactions where too slow.  It was suggested that i use cache which will be much faster, in this case i will be storing my cart in a session but the session driver will be either memcached or redis, i though this was just as simple as changing the drivers but it looks like i was wrong.

I tried both and ended up getting 'class' not found for each of them, so i looked for a redis package and installed it but then it said "connection refused' after several attempts i still couldn't get it to work so i decided to find how to install and use memcached drivers in laravel 5 but it seems there is very little (useful) information regarding this, been searching for almost an hour now.

I use laravel-5 via the built in PHP development server on windows 8.  My question is how do i install and configure either one of those drivers to use in my application.

Answer (score -1):

Hy,

has you shown to develop on a virtual mashine too? It is I think the best and easiest way to develop modern applications. Laravel has a own vagrant implentation with name: homestead. But I dont know homestead has a redis implementation but memcached is implemented. If [homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead) dont have redis implemented you can configure your own vagrant box by using [puphet.com](https://puphpet.com/#create) website.

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: Hello, sorry i don't get it, are you saying this will solve my problem?

Comment: Hy, I understand you that you dont know how you can install redis or memcached on windows 8. With a virtual mashine or a vagrant box (build virtual mashine from the scratch) from [puphpet.com](https://puphpet.com) at example you can configure your own development stack with the tools and feature you need.